# Ionic 3: How to calculate sum of values in sets of arrays

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I have few sets of array which looks like this 
[image]

How can i sum up all the cartTotal?

in my ts file code are like this

with this method i am getting constantly 0 as answer

```
itemTotal() {
    let total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < this.bag.length; i++) {
      if (this.bag[i].cartTotal) {
        total += Number(this.bag[i].cartTotal);
      }
    }
    return total;
  }
```

How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cartTotal` is an attribute, in your code you have an array and inside of it multiple objects. The simplest thing to do is:

```
let sum = 0;
for (let car of this.bag) {
  sum = sum + car.cartTotal;
 }
console.log(sum);
```

---

After speaking with OP, the data is getting added to `this.bag` in the following way:

```
this.storage.get('products').then(data => { 
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { 
     //console.log(data[i]) 
     this.bag.push(data[i]); 
      } 
   });
```

Since `.then()` is called asynchronously then any operating using `this.bag` after `.then()` will not return data.

To solve this do the following:

```
this.storage.get('products').then(data => 
{ 
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) 
  { 
   //console.log(data[i]) 
   this.bag.push(data[i]); 
  } 
this.itemChecks();
});

 itemChecks() 
 {
  for (let car of this.bag) { 
    this.sum = this.sum + car.cartTotal; 
    console.log(sum) 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Yes I did and its showing same for all :( 
Answer is 0

Comment: Do inside this loop `console.log(car)` and tell me what you get

Comment: Nothing. The loop isnt running i guess

Comment: where are you calling `itemTotal()`?

Comment: inside ionViewDidLoad()

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190230/discussion-between-peter-haddad-and-xyne).

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` for calculation.

Like

```
const total = [yourArray].reduce((total, nextObj) => {
  return total + nextObj.cartTotal;

}, 0);

console.log(total)
```

For more information about reduce function, follow the guideline.
[Array.prototype.reuce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Returning the same answer as before. I guess its not calculation the numbers :(

Comment: Well, I did some calculations for you. Check over here.
https://jsbin.com/yohuwayucu/edit?js,console

Comment: Ok. So that means my this.bag.cartTotal is not returning the proper value

Answer (score 1):

You'd simply use reduce

```
const total = this.bag.reduce((a,b) => a + b.cartTotal, 0);
```

The error in your code is that you'd need to access the `i` element of `this.bag`, rather than the undefined `this.bag.cartTotal[i]`. <-- Doesn't exist, should be `this.bag[i].cartTotal`

Comment: it is still returning answer as 0